# transfer data as day changes to another table.

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php code...

```
<?php
    require("conn.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM temp";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     ?>    
       <label>1. <?php echo $line[0]; ?></label><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="one_quarter">
      <label >2. <?php echo $line[1]; ?></label><br/>
    <?php
              }
              mysqli_close($con);
     ?>
```

`Temp` table contain 3 columns i.e. `r1`,`r2`,`days`. here I am displaying `r1` and `r2`. And days contain day name. If suppose day name is Monday then I want to display `r1` and `r2` in another html table on Tuesday. Notice that I am saying on Tuesday. That html table remain empty on Monday but when Tuesday comes then values of `r1`,`r2` for Monday should be displayed in that html table.
It should like this [image]
Means if two names which are displaying above are for monday then on tuesday, that both names should be displayed in below html table. Remember on tuesday.

I want to display that two values in html table in monday column automatically on tuesday.

It it possible with cron job?

Comment: so in the end what should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo date('F jS, Y', strtotime('Monday next week  2014-12-18'));
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php